jalali date picker Material Design WPF C#
I have a WPF application .net Framework platform and in the Xaml Side, I have changed the Culture as follows: When I use DatePicker, when I click on the date selection button, it shows me the Persian calendar correctly. However, when I select a date, it displays the Gregorian date in Persian numbers. When I click on the year at the top of the page to select the date, it shows me the Gregorian months in Persian. Then, when I click again, it shows me the Gregorian years. What should I do to solve this problem?

when I Select a date in Date Piker it Also Translate to Gregorian Calendar. and its Look Like This:

The Xaml code that I wrote for this date Picker is as follows:
<DatePicker
  Width="140" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
  BorderThickness="2" Margin="8" Language="fa-IR" 
  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="تاریخ پایان"
  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedDatePicker}" />

What I want is to be able to convert the months and years in Datepicker to the Jalali calendar, and after selecting, the Jalali date will be displayed in the text box.
Can this confusion in the Jalali and Gregorian calendars be resolved?
I would be grateful if you could help me in this regard.
What I want is to be able to convert the months and years in Datepicker to the Jalali calendar, and after selecting, the Jalali date will be displayed in the text box.

Is there a reason for setting the culture on the control (Language=)? What happens if you set the UI culture for the entire application, in the constructor of App.xaml.cs:
cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

You might also have to set the non-UI culture:
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

Does this fix the problem? Perhaps there is a bug with the DatePicker control, and the Language="" attribute only affects the calendar popup but not the textbox.

Thank you for the answer @Andrew Stephens
I completed your code, but this code only caused the numbers to be displayed in Farsi language and the date was still in Gregorian format
Also, the dates are in the Gregorian calendar and do not follow the Jalali date. tis is my code:

' public partial class App : Application
{
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
base.OnStartup(e);
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    }
}'


I think setting culture is not enough for material design datepicker to show dates properly

It might be an idea to test this in a standalone app but without the material design library. This should tell you whether the problem is with the control itself or the date picker template in the MD library. If it's the latter you can raise a bug on their GitHub page.

hello again
I did what you said and added it in a separate project using the date picker in Visual Studio's own toolbox and also didn't use the material library. Then I added all the things you said in the answer section to App.Zaml. But unfortunately, only the names of the months of the year have been Persianized, for example: "August" was changed to "اوت" and no other changes were observed.Even the numbers were not changed in Persian and were displayed in English.Also, my Bug report can be seen on the material design github issues page, but no one has responded yet.
